# no puedo correro php en mi blog

Tags: php, netbeans

Necesito ayuda por favor.
Quiero cargar mi blog pero cuando intento ver en mi la web me figuran los errores. 
Estoy siguiendo los videotutoriales java deb one.

```sh
Notice: Undefined variable: nombre_servidor in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\conexion.inc.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: nombre_base_datos in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\conexion.inc.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: nombre_usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\conexion.inc.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\conexion.inc.php on line 10
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)br>
```

Comment: Puedes subir tu código de conexion.inc.php

Comment: Estas intentando conectar con una base de datos pero no tienes definidas las variables para ello. Los errores indican que las intentas utilizar en la linea 10 pero no están definidas o iniciadas antes, provocando un error al intentar la conexión.

Comment: Joanquin, gracias por la ayuda. 
Me dirías como hacerlo?